# Difference between "python a/b.py" and "python -m a.b"

Tags: python

When I run `python a/b.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a/b.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config'
```

When I run `python -m a.b`, I get no error.

What is the fundamental difference between the two approaches?

Comment: Judging from your error this is an issue of relative imports. Check out the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) has a little more info on being able to run a file both ways you have listed

Comment: IMHO, as a general rule, if `a` is a package **never** run anything inside it. It's usually better if whoever makes/distributes the package to provide some external script that does stuff (e.g. using `setuptools`'s `console_scripts`).